Why is Textview height larger than the text height in Android?
I'm trying to place an element under the Textview but there is too much space between them because the Textview has too much padding and this padding can't be disabled.
I even tested it with just one element in the page and still it has the same problem:
<TextView android:id="@+id/textViewSpeed" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="test" android:textColor="@color/black" android:fontFamily="monospace" android:textSize="150sp"  android:padding="0dp"/>
Setting padding to 0 doesn't make the border of the Textview touch the text, there seems to be a minimal padding.
This is how it looks in my real app:

There is an unused space between the radio buttons and the text.

I found out in another answer here to use this:       android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp" , it helps a little bit but still doens't elimate the whole padding.

AFAIK, TextView reserves space on a line for ascenders and descenders.

Its a duplicated case:
Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom
However to understand the space extra you have to add. I;ll show only here how I already added the attribute:
android:includeFontPadding="false"

Check the image below to see the results:
https://ibb.co/QJQJhyV


Thanks, I only need to use digi/ts there however. I don't suppose there is a built in solution for displaying digits without padding is there?
